# Can the Cost attribute scope be changed to Store View?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product-attribute, products-management, scope, internationalization

The cost attribute (not the price) is locked to "Website". We have a situation where we sell the same product in different countries and as such the cost of the product is actually different. For example the landed cost to the USA may be $5, but the landed cost to the UK is $7.50.

We'd like to be able to run Magento's reports and see the total product sales/profit. And we'd like to be able to see the sales/profit for the USA store and for the the UK store separately. We would do this based on Websites instead (and do Show Report For: All Websites), but we have other websites on the same Magento installation so this wouldn't give us the data we need.

There is no built in way to change the Cost attribute to Store View, but if we were to manually do so would it cause any problems?

What is the best way to make the change? Modifying the DB, or creating a module that does it, or?

What are the potential problems with doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento all the price attributes are limited to `global` or `website` scope. The reason for this is that store views represent facets of the same thing. Usually a store view represents a language and customers should not pay more because they order from a different language.
The same thing applies to the cost attribute.
You could change magento to allow prices at store view scope but you risk breaking the pricing logic.
Instead you could create a different website and assign store views to the new website. This way you could implement your logic without touching the code.

Comment: It does seem that short of making major changes this is our only option. It does complicate things for us though since it will break stats in to separate websites instead of part of a single website. But, we'll make due. Thanks for taking the time to reply.